# Using pin number to access a form

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm creating a web application form for which I want a user to pay for first before access is granted to the form.

Pay and obtain the PIN number then enter that number, if the number is correct then access granted, else...

Answer (score 0):

you must first have the pin number in your database then send that number to the one who paid for it, then compare the input with the one in the database. but you should've at least done some coding or at least tried something by yourself so we code copy and paste your code and fixe it for you.